# Prevent iframe content to go into a new line

Tags: html, css, iframe

After googling for a good time, I couldn't find the answer I was looking for.

Simple question:

How do I force the content of an iframe to wrap into the next line instead of generating a horizontal scrollbar? Max-width and width in the body is lovingly ignored by the text.

Comment: This could be because the content you are loading has a `min-width`. In this case there is no way around it using iFrame with that specific content.

Comment: @CharlieFish There is no "min-" anything anywhere...

Comment: What is your width and heigh of your iFrame and what is the URL you are trying to put in the iFrame?

Comment: @CharlieFish The iframe is 1599 pixel wide and and 692 pixel high. The contents loaded into the iframe are different sub-pages created by myself. The main website just contains a menu bar and a logo.

Comment: What happens if you load those sub-pages in your browser and set the width and height of your browser to those dimensions? Is there a scroll bar?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. When I have to make a demo with an iframe I use [Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/),

Comment: @CharlieFish Yup... So I guess it's not an issue with the iframe, but rather with the content page itself..

Comment: @zer00ne Sadly, I can't. I have this problem on a project at work where we don't have internet access, and I can't write down all the lines on my phone...

Comment: @CodingWolf Yeah, so making that site responsive and having it adapt to the width of the browser will fix your problem. Bootstrap has some good solutions for this. But try to make your CSS use `%` as much as you can instead of `px`.